# Custom wordpress theme

Tags: html, wordpress

So I have been using the foundation framework to create my website. Its full of HTML,CSS,JS and images. I was looking at a tutorial from HTML to Wordpress conversion. I understanding having separate files called header.php, footer.php, aside.php and index.php.

What I don't understand that has not been spoken about is I have 3 pages in my website. HOME , ABOUTUS and FAQ. They all have the same footer and header. Is the index.php a template for the actual theme from which I can build upon to create the other pages or do I have to do this process manually for each file.

Comment: Read this first: http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development and http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy. You need to understand the WordPress theme naming convention and schema. Or you could use http://foundationpress.olefredrik.com/ and style accordingly (Foundation for WordPress).

Answer (score 1):

the index.php is your front page. The page.php file includes your pages but you have to create the file. Please read a tutorial how to do this. If you would like to create a page you should copy the content from your HOME, ABOUTUS, FAQ in the textfield in wordpress where you create your pages. HTML is allowed it should be no problem but you have to remove the header and footer from HOME, ABOUTUS and FAQ because you include it in your theme. If you would like to use a menu on your website which display the links to your pages you have to register a menu in your functions.php and to include it in the header, footer, page.php, index.php etc. But read a tutorial, please. After that you should know how to create a WordPress theme

Comment: so when I create my template which will be the index.php page. From here I can use this template and create my other pages and add the contents of them, not including any header or footer information. Is that what you are trying to aim? @speedDeveloper

Comment: yes you should do creating the content of your pages in the wordpress gui. Before you develop a own theme you can test the output on an other theme.